# How do I make my Android app insert record only if it doesn't exist else display a Toast or Message?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I need to enter username & password in edittext & store them into a database on clicking a button. They shoud be stored only if the any other record doesn't have same username. This one causes app to crash

```
public void updateDB(){
    username = editTextUser.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " +UserDatabase.TABLE1+" where"+UserDatabase.USERNAME+" ='" +username+ "'",null);
    if (cursor.getCount()==0) {
        values.put(UserDatabase.USERNAME,username);
        values.put(UserDatabase.PASSWORD,password);
        try {
            db.insert(UserDatabase.TABLE1, null, values);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("SignUpActivity", username + " " + password);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Username NA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I love a good question. This isn't one.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Method for Checking User Already Exist's or Not.

```
// For UserName[Person] Already Exist
    public String ExistsValidation(String PersonName) {
        String PName = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, PERSON_NAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(PersonName).trim()}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                return PName;
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                PName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PersonName"));
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
        return PName;
    }
```

Use above Method Like :

```
    String PersonName = etPersonName.getText().toString().trim();
    String storedPersonName = db.ExistsValidation(PersonName);

    // if PersonName Exists
    if (PersonName.equals(storedPersonName)) {
        ShowAlertDialog("Error..!", "PersonName Already Exists,Enter Another Name");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: and You only need to Check for Already UserName not for Password...
Because Password should same for one or more User's

Comment: Have you checked `cursor == null`? A cursor will not be null if there are no rows returned. You should instead check the count. e.g. `(cursor.getCount() == 0)` or `(cursor.getCount() < 1)`

Answer (score -1):

you can use insertOrThrow() method instead,just put an UNIQUE keyword before username in table and introduce an new

```
catch with(SQLException e){}
```

in this you can toast you messsage

Comment: It is always throwing exception. Tel exactly where do I put UNIQUE?

Comment: add UNIQUE where you write create table statment for your database add this keyword before username
e.g. `create table user if not exists (username  UNIQUE varchar,....)`